# Virtualbox crashes quite often in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I just installed Windows 8 on my computer.
I got the ISO and the product key from my university so the software itself is sound.

I use alot of virtual box.
And ever since I moved to Windows 8, I have noticed that virtual box crashes more often.
In particular, it is very very bad at opening multiple guests. My CPU usage will be at like 20% and I only have 3 guests open and my entire computer just freezes. Cursor and all.
In Windows 7, I was able to open like 6 (not that I ever needed to) and really push my CPU.

I havent experience any other issues with Windows 8 yet.

Has anyone encountered this?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that Windows 8 Pro has Hyper-V bundled with it (not installed by default) I only encountered an issue (VirtualBox VMs won't even boot up) after installing Hyper-V. You can always switch to Hyper-V (or at least try it, like I'm doing now) instead of VirtualBox

Answer (score 1):

Ask it in the [official Virtualbox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/) or create a [ticket in tracker](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker).

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox crashes very often in Windows 7 and Windows 8 on my i3 with Radeon laptop. You could either try Hyper-V (if you're using Windows 8 Pro, and your hardware supports it), or try VMWare Player